# Lower casing column values dynamically

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have a mysql script and I want to convert a column value to be always in lower case. I don't want to use trigger. When I run my hibernate code and fill data in DB I want a column value to be always in lowercase.

Is there is any way I can use Lower() function of mysql during table creation so that every time data is inserted it is lower Case?

I saw many examples of lowercase but all are update operation.

Comment: Apparently, there's no way to do it without using a trigger.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Hibernate interceptor (see an [example here](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-interceptor-example-audit-log/))

In the method

```
public boolean onSave(Object entity,Serializable id,
    Object[] state,String[] propertyNames,Type[] types)
```

You can check whether the entity is instance of your class to be lowercased and update necessary fields with lower cased values.

Or just in the entity extend setters to convert to the lowercase on call.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have an entity like:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners(MyEntityListener.class)
public class MyEntity {
    private String name;
    ...
}
```

and EntityListener like:

```
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;

public class MyEntityListener {

    @PrePersist
    public void entityPrePersist(MyEntity obj) {
        if (obj != null && obj.getName() != null) {
            obj.setName(obj.getName().toLowerCase());       
        }
        // ... same to other properties
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro it's not working.. I tried exactly same thing as u told

Comment: @user9966539 that's weird. Did you debug? Or any errors in logs? Maybe you can update your question with some example?